# When using scrollRectToVisible(), it need invoke twice to fix position correctly. How to fix?

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jpanel, jscrollpane

My case is: There are 2 tab views in my project, Tab A view display list and Tab B display charts in JScrollPane.
Feature is: Click one list item in Tab A, it will go to Tab B and scroll to the pointed Chart X (maybe the first one, or the second....)

Problem is: If click one item in Tab A, Tab B view scrolls to the last chart (at the bottom of JScrollPane). Then go to Tab A, click another item, Tab B **should** scroll to the first chart (at the top of JScrollPane).
However, JScrollPane is still fixed at the bottom.
But if i go to Tab A and click the same item **agian**, Tab B can scroll to the first chart, correctly.

Codes as below:

> protected void buildUI()
>      {
>          setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
>
> ```
>    myChartPanel = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
>
>    // add different charts for different Item in Tab A
>    myChartPanel.add(..) 
>
>    myGraphViewPane = new JScrollPane();
>    Border scrollPaneBorder = myGraphViewPane.getBorder();
>    myGraphViewPane.setBorder( null );
>
>    //Set single graph view visible by default
>    myGraphViewPane.setViewportView( myChartPanel );
>
>    add( myGraphViewPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
>    setBorder( scrollPaneBorder );
> ```
>
> }

I have tried below scroll codes, none work well:

> myChartPanel.scrollRectToVisible( focusChart.getBounds() );

or

> myGraphViewPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue( focusChart.getLocation().x );

or

> myGraphViewPane.getViewport().setViewPosition(new Point( focusChart.getLocation().x, chartView.getLocation().y ) );

Why only click twice, it could scroll to correct position? So strange!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: there no isssue, nor with centering in the JViewport, no idea whats happened in your case(invokeLater is useless, because this methods has smoot scrolling), for better help sooner post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable demonstrated a.m. issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to wrap the `myChartPanel.scrollRectToVisible( focusChart.getBounds() );` call in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`